# Arduino/Unity semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino

After a short time, I have the game that freeze and this exception :

> Semaphore timeout period has expired

Unity just send data to the arduino

```
Start(){
        port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
        port.ReadTimeout = 50;
        port.WriteTimeout = 100;
        port.Open();
}

Update(){
       port.write("$$$");
}
```

And of course I close the port at the end.

For the arduino I just use SerialCommand.h. I tried a lot of things : changing the cable, changing the port, the drivers, ... but nothing seem to be working
Do you have an idea?